# Added a guest network to a Cisco router, can't get the space to NAT

Tags: cisco, nat

Device: Cisco SR520W-FE

I have added a guest wireless network to this router but I can't seem to get nat overload to work with the new space.

LAN: 192.168.5.0/24 (VLAN 75)
Guest WLAN: 10.5.5.0/24 (VLAN 50)

Here is the commands I'm using for the NAT overload

```
interface FastEthernet0
 switchport access vlan 75

interface FastEthernet3
 switchport access vlan 50

 interface FastEthernet4
 ip address x.x.x.x 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly

interface Vlan50
 ip address 10.5.5.1 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 120 out
 ip nat inside

interface BVI75
 ip address 192.168.5.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly

ip nat inside source list 10 interface FastEthernet3 overload
ip nat inside source route-map SDM_RMAP_1 interface FastEthernet4 overload

route-map SDM_RMAP_1 permit 1
 match ip address 101

access-list 10 remark PAT IP space for the guest WLAN
access-list 10 permit 10.5.5.0 0.0.0.255

access-list 101 deny   ip 192.168.5.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.76.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.5.0 0.0.0.255 any

access-list 120 remark ACL to block guest wireless from LAN
access-list 120 deny   ip 10.5.5.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
access-list 120 permit ip 10.5.5.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was "NATing" the physical interface and not the SVI. Once I did that everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's been ages since I've done this, so my apologies if I missed something obvious, but... aren't you missing something like

ip nat pool "address of your external interface" ?

Comment: The LAN nat overload is currently working so I don't think that command is needed. I'm not sure if the "ip nat outside" command is what is making it work or not.